# Flask send_from_directory() for production purposes

Tags: python, apache, flask

In my `app.py` file, I have

```
@app.route('get_item')
def get_item():
    id = request.args.get('id')
    # if id is in database (if request is valid):
        send_from_directory('files', 'file.ext', as_attachment=True)
    else:
        abort(403)
```

I have read in numerous SO posts that using Flask to serve static files is a bad idea for production purposes. What should I do instead if I am planning on using an Apache server for production?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need some rewrite rules so that Apache can find the files, something like this:

```
Alias /static/ /var/www/hello-world/static
```

And redirect to apache when needed:

```
id = request.args.get('id')
# if id is in database (if request is valid):
    return redirect('/files/file.ext') # use the correct url written in rewrite rules
else:
    abort(403)
```

Comment: But this would allow anyone to access the file from the direct URL. How would I prevent direct access to the file and instead only send the file if the  ID is valid?